# Creating columnstore Index on existing partitioned table with 800+ million rows on SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017, columnstore

I have partition table (on date) with B-Tree clustered index which contains more than 800 million rows.

I would like to create a clustered columnstore index on this table in place of existing clustered index, what would be the most efficient way?

Does this affect my existing primary key which has been created with B-tree clustered index?

Is there anything else do I need to do to make my columnstore index align with existing partition of table?

Please guide.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ORDHDR](
        [DATE_DWID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [VERSION] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [LOCATION_DWID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [START_LOC_DWID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [DESTINATION_LOC_DWID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [XFY_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [START_DWID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [END_DWID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [START_REQ_DWID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [END_IYF_DWID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [CREATED_AT_DWID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [TIME_OF_IPB_DWID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [DATAREC_NUM] [int] NOT NULL,
        [REQUEST_FOR_DATA_TRANSFER] [varchar](30) NULL,
        [DATAPCKT_NUM] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
        [INTERNAL_NUM_FOR_SUPPLY] [varchar](30) NULL,
        [SOURCE_SUPPLY] [varchar](60) NULL,
        [RECORD_MODE] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [ORD_TYPE] [varchar](3) NULL,
        [APO_ORD] [varchar](12) NULL,
        [APO_APPLICATION] [int] NULL,
        [SUPPLY_CATEGORY] [varchar](12) NULL,
        [CONVERTABLE_ORD] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [ORDSTATUS_OUTPUT] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [ORDSTATUS_INPUT] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [PARTIAL_DELIVERY_STATUS] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [FINAL_DELIVERY_INDICATOR] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [STATUS_DEALLOCATED] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [STATUS_RELEASED] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [STATUS_FIXED] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [STATUS_STARTED] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [ORD_COMPONENT_ISSUED] [int] NULL,
        [PARTIALLY_CONFIRMED] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [FINAL_CONFORMATION] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [ORD_PLNG_TYPE] [int] NULL,
        [ORD_STATUS] [int] NULL,
        [START_TIME_OF_ACTIVITY] [varchar](15) NULL,
        [END_DATE_OF_LATEST_ACTIVITY] [varchar](15) NULL,
        [FLAG] [varchar](1) NULL,
        [EDW_CREATE_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
        [EDW_UPDATE_DATE] [datetime] NULL
    ) ON [ORD_PS]([DATE_DWID])

    GO

    CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [ORD_HDR_PK] ON [dbo].[ORDHDR]
    (
        [DATE_DWID] ASC,
        [VERSION] ASC,
        [LOCATION_DWID] ASC,
        [START_LOC_DWID] ASC,
        [DESTINATION_LOC_DWID] ASC,
        [XFY_ID] ASC,
        [START_DWID] ASC,
        [END_DWID] ASC,
        [START_REQ_DWID] ASC,
        [END_IYF_DWID] ASC,
        [CREATED_AT_DWID] ASC,
        [TIME_OF_IPB_DWID] ASC,
        [DATAREC_NUM] ASC,
        [DATAPCKT_NUM] ASC
    )
```

Comment: Add DDL for your existing table to your question for clarity. You mentioned the existing table is partitioned by date and has a clustered primary key index. This implies the existing clustered primary key includes the partitioning column, assuming indexes are aligned. Are you wanting to remove the existing primary key entirely?

Comment: I want all existing key and constraints. only thing I want is turning my existing B-tree clustered index into Column-store clustered index. and its impact on existing design.     I have added the DDL

Comment: I don't see a primary key or any other constraints in your DDL. Do you mean the unique clustered index when you said primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a clustered columnstore index has only columns and no keys, you'll need to change the existing unique clustered index to a clustered columnstore index to convert the rowstore table into a columnstore and then create a new non-clustered b-tree index to enforce uniqueness.

This can be accomplished with the `DROP_EXISTING=ON` clause of [`CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql) followed by creation of the new index.

```
--change existing clustered index to clustered columnstore
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX ORD_HDR_PK ON [dbo].[ORDHDR]
    WITH(DROP_EXISTING=ON) ON [ORD_PS]([DATE_DWID]);

--rename columnstore index to a more meaningful name
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.ORDHDR.ORD_HDR_PK','ccidx_ORDHDR', 'INDEX';

--create new non-clustered unique index
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ORD_HDR_PK] ON [dbo].[ORDHDR]
    (
        [DATE_DWID] ASC,
        [VERSION] ASC,
        [LOCATION_DWID] ASC,
        [START_LOC_DWID] ASC,
        [DESTINATION_LOC_DWID] ASC,
        [XFY_ID] ASC,
        [START_DWID] ASC,
        [END_DWID] ASC,
        [START_REQ_DWID] ASC,
        [END_IYF_DWID] ASC,
        [CREATED_AT_DWID] ASC,
        [TIME_OF_IPB_DWID] ASC,
        [DATAREC_NUM] ASC,
        [DATAPCKT_NUM] ASC
    ) ON [ORD_PS]([DATE_DWID]);
```

Comment: My main intention is how are underlying table partitions take care when column-store index is created.

Comment: The partitions will be the same with both rowstore and columnstore when the same partition scheme is used. Also, the new non-clustered b-tree index is partitioned using the same scheme so the columnstore table and b-tree index are aligned.

Comment: Dan, Can you please guide me with maintenance as well for clustered columnstore index. that is how efficiently can we keep this index up to date  with things like fragmentation and statistics.

Comment: Consider using this popular [maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/).